# roscd not working on 13.04

Tags: ros, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just installed ros-hydro-stage-ros, but I can't seem to find roscd.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139291/roscd-not-working-on-13.04/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2022 on 2014-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that ros-hydro-rosbash isn't a dependency for stage-ros, so:

> sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rosbash

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2014-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0